# Using Android service context for Room database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-room

I'm working on an App that uses both **Firebase Messaging** and **Room database**.

This is how the db is initialized

```
public static AppDatabase getInstance(final Context appContext) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase.class, "dbname.db")
                // prepopulate the database after onCreate was called
                .addCallback(rdc)
                .build();
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}
```

Somewhere on `MainActivity` the first call to `AppDatabase` is made and the database is instantiated, all is working fine and dandy!

Now the problem starts when the user `kill` the app...

For the sake of simplicity think of this App like **Whatsapp**... the application got killed but the `service (MyFirebaseMessagingService)` that is listening for messages is still running (as it should).

When a new message arrives and `MyFirebaseMessagingService` tries to save it to the database with a call to `AppDatabase.getInstance()` a crash will occur since the initial `context` reference on witch the database was created no longer exists because the application was killed.

Searching on how to solve this I learned that every service `this` is actually derived from `context` so I immediately tried to use the `MyFirebaseMessagingService` context to initialize the database, however, `MyFirebaseMessagingService::onCreate` where you really have access to the service context don't get fired until the first message arrives

The only solution I can think of is creating a completely new service, `bindService()` it to the MainActivity, and use that new service context to create the AppDatabase instance... but it seems completely overkill.

So my question is, how can initialize the Room Database in a way that `MyFirebaseMessagingService` can still use it even if the App was killed?

Comment: you have access to getApplicationContext() in a Service, have you tried that? The Application instance should be created before any Service, Activity or Broadcast Receiver is created.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: service based context.getApplicationContext() is null. It is crashing. Any other suggested solution.

Answer (score 2):

`getApplicationContext()` is not available in the constructor function. But it's available inside `onStartCommand()` function. I think that's a good place to build/open the database in a service.

Answer (score 0):

Since `FirebaseMessagingService` is a service we should have `getApplicationContext()` there, you should use that to create an instance of your dB and do the necessary operations,
The other options are to create a service or write a custom broadcast receiver.

Answer (score -1):

First: from a system context (NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) you are trying to use Room that uses the app context to access or create the database. 
But the app context might be null in that moment. Maybe just because the app got killed. 
So you get a nice crash.

Second, some logs would be nice. With the crash. It might keep people from guessing.

Third: (Again a guess) Maybe you should try Work manager. Something like: you receive data > start work. Will run reliably and do not have to run right in that moment.
A great place to start [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager?gclid=CjwKCAjwm-fkBRBBEiwA966fZGsCHREP-uZcK55xkWGfSDsn3cfSA9tJdutlODDd0CBWxh0Vn6Iw5xoCbmsQAvD_BwE)